# Can't log into new Bukkit Server install

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

I am setting up a new MineCraft server and would like to use Bukkit but when I try to connect with the client I get "IP Address lost connection" within the server window and within the client I get "Can't connect to server" even on the localhost.

I completely turned off my Windows Firewall and am now getting java.netConnectException: Connection refused:  no further information:"

I set up vanilla Minecraft and that works fine.  I have port forwarding on, although it wouldn't impact the localhost attempts. With vanilla MineCraft I can connect from another PC but Bukkit is getting the same error no matter where I try to connect from.

CraftBukkit version git-Bukkit-1.6.4-R2.0-b2918jnks  
Windows 8
memory set to 3G on an 8G system

I have seen multiple of the same issue but the few fixes I have found did not work (turn off online mode, setting op user, adjusting memory, etc.

Comment: Are you running on the right versions of Bukkit and Minecraft?

Comment: Robert, I was able to finally resolve this.  Although I downloaded the recommended version I went ahead and downloaded a newer Development version and it is now working.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with the server!

Answer (score -3):

Download notepad+++ or edit the run in ur server full at the end it put true right?
Make true to false and u use localhost and u will connect to it

Comment: This answer is a little unclear. Is there any chance you could clarify or expand on it a bit?

Comment: Please use proper English spelling and grammar.